# execute code every 5 minute and finish it after 2 minutes. CountDownTimer or Handler?

Tags: android

In android I need to execute some code every 5 minutes and finish it after 2 minutes when running.

What is better to use:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

or

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

I know how to implement both but I don't know what is better and what use less memory and battery=

Comment: A CountDownTimer is nothing more than a Handler with specialized features and the CountDownTimer's methods are not a perfect match for your task. Of the two, I recommend a Handler. But Handlers really only work inside a foreground Activity...

Comment: Look for android wakeful service

Comment: and what if i need it also in sleep mode? Then I need AlarmManager?

Comment: Yes use alarm manager and wakeful service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. Use `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`, with the `IntentService` doing the work and abandoning it after two minutes if the work is not yet completed.

Comment: how to abandoning the IntentService after 2 minutes? By running thread for 2 minutes or something else?

Comment: @mbrc: After two minutes, stop doing work and return from `onHandleIntent()`.